# Modify MySQL field based on another with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that I'm needing to change one field based on another. There are two records for each id "option_id." Each have a sort_order.

```
So for example:
12345, 1
12345, 2
```

I need to be able to find any records that have the same ID and have one for sort_order 1, and one for sort_order 2. Then, I need to change the sort_order of 1 to 0, and the sort_order of 2 to 1. I'd like to use php to do this is possible.

Comment: Do the row have an ID field to identify one specific row, regardless of the `option_id` and `sort_order`?

Comment: Events in case you use doctrine for example

Comment: No, no ID field other than the option_id which has two records each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can handle the connection strings yourself, (I'm assuming PDO here). I had to do number swapping almost exactly like this very recently.

Then do the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sort_order = 2";
    while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $sql_1 = "UPDATE table set sort_order = 0 WHERE sort_order = 1 AND option_type_id = " . $row['option_id']; //then execute query
        $sql_2 = "UPDATE table set sort_order = 1 WHERE sort_order = 2 AND option_type_id = " . $row['option_id']; //then execute query.
    }
```

The logic is that you find the matching record, change the 1 to 0, then change the 2 to 1. Doing the opposite would really mess up the records.

Comment: *Note: I left out the actual query executions. I figured you can handle that part.

Comment: Thanks! That got me where I need to go.